# AMD not working ubuntu 15.04

Tags: 64-bit, 15.04

I just updated to 15.04 on my PC and the graphics on the entire system are off a lot. I downloaded AMD and i cannot open and run it.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'` terminal command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click the Ubuntu Symbol in the top left corner and type Software and Updates then click the Software and Updates icon that appears then choose Additional Drivers at the top right of the box. Give it time to scan your system for the drivers then choose the one that best suits you. It may take a minute to scan for the drivers so be patient.